# Bison working with non-terminals

Tags: bison

The following code was compiling correctly until I added the 'float' rules, then it gave me errors that i listed below any help would be appreciated.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define YYSTYPE double

int yylex(void);

static
void yyerror(char *s)
{
printf("yyerror: %s\n", s);
}

%}


%union{
  int       int_val;
  string*   op_val;
}

%token PLUS
%token MINUS
%token MULT
%token DIVIDE

%token LPAREN
%token RPAREN

%token Unsigned_float
%token UNSIGNEDINTEGER

%left PLUS MINUS
%left MULT DIVIDE

%%

lines     :         lines expr   '\n'         {printf("%g\n", $2);}
|                    lines '\n'
|                   /*empty*/
;

expr      :          expr PLUS  expr           {$$  =  $1  +  $3;}  
|                   expr MINUS  expr           {$$  =  $1  -  $3;} 
|                   expr MULT  expr           {$$  =  $1  *  $3;} 
|                    expr DIVIDE  expr           {$$  =  $1  /  $3;} 
|                   LPAREN  expr  RPAREN        {$$ =  $2;}
|                   UNSIGNEDINTEGER        
;

 float     : Unsigned_float PLUS  Unsigned_float           {$$  =  $1  +  $3;}  
|                    Unsigned_float MINUS  Unsigned_float           {$$  =  $1      -  $3;} 
|                    Unsigned_float MULT  Unsigned_float           {$$  =  $1  *  $3;} 
|                    Unsigned_float DIVIDE  Unsigned_float           {$$  =  $1  /  $3;} 
|                    LPAREN  Unsigned_float  RPAREN        {$$ =  $2;}       
;



%%

#include  "lex.yy.c"

int yylex(void);
int yyparse(void);

int main(void)
{
return yyparse();
}
```

here are the errors:

```
stojk_3_4.y:40.63-64: $2 of `lines' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:45.49-50: $$ of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:45.56-57: $1 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:45.63-64: $3 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:46.61-62: $$ of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:46.68-69: $1 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:46.75-76: $3 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:47.60-61: $$ of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:47.67-68: $1 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:47.74-75: $3 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:48.63-64: $$ of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:48.70-71: $1 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:48.77-78: $3 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:49.62-63: $$ of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:49.68-69: $2 of `expr' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:53.60-61: $$ of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:53.67-68: $1 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:53.74-75: $3 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:54.82-83: $$ of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:54.89-90: $1 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:54.96-97: $3 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:55.81-82: $$ of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:55.88-89: $1 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:55.95-96: $3 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:56.83-84: $$ of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:56.90-91: $1 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:56.97-98: $3 of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:57.73-74: $$ of `float' has no declared type
stojk_3_4.y:57.79-80: $2 of `float' has no declared type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use both `YYSTYPE` and `%union`. I'm pretty sure that doing this will cause the parser to not compile. (However, `bison` probably doesn't detect that.)

If you specify `%union`, then you must tell `bison` which of the `union` members (by tagname) applies to each terminal and non-terminal. You do this with the `%type` declaration for non-terminals, and `%token` for terminals, as follows:

```
%type <int_val> expr
%token <op_val> PLUS MINUS
```

(Those are *just examples.* **Do not just copy them.** You need to think this through depending on what you're doing with the values.)

If you specify `%union` *every* terminal and non-terminal -- or at least, the ones whose value is used -- must have a type specification; otherwise, `bison` will produce the error message you see. If you do not specify `%union`, then you don't need to declare types because every terminal and non-terminal has the same type, which is whatever `YYSTYPE` is.